# How do I solve this composite function and find its domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I solve the composite function? And what would the domain for it be?

$$f(x)=-x^2+1\,\quad    g(x)=\sqrt x$$

$$(g \circ f)(x) = \quad ?$$

Comment: Hint: The domain of $g\circ f$ is $\{x : f(x) \in dom(g)\}$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=-x^2+1 = 1 - x^2,\quad    g(x)=\sqrt x$$

$$(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)= g(1-x^2 )=\sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

Now, for the domain of $(g\circ f)(x):\quad $ When is $1-x^2 \geq 0\quad ?\quad$

The domain consists of all real numbers such that $1 \geq x^2 \iff x^2 \leq 1$.

Comment: Clear write up +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance

> $$ h(x)=g(f(x))=g(1-x^2 )=\sqrt{1-x^2}. $$

Now, try to find the domain of $h(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally,
$${\rm dom\ } f\circ g = g^{-1} ({\rm dom\ }f)$$
where $\cdot^{-1}$ is the preimage (not necessarily the inverse).
Here
$${\rm dom\ } g\circ f = f^{-1} ([0, \infty)) = \{ x : 1-x^2 \in [0, \infty) \} = [-1,1]$$